# Tracing in MVC web API Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a good framework for tracing activities in asp.net MVC. 
I've implemented registration to action filters with in ActionFilterAttribute. 
But I want to have see all activities like WCF tracing offers.
Since the operation is posting to service , I want it to be traced to file like tracing in WCF.

10x, 
Rony

Comment: See [ASP.NET Tracing Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Or maybe StackExchange's own [MVC Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now I found a nice thing.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="app.log"  />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/).  Glimpse is an easy way to view tracing activities.

Comment: <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="api.log"  />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

Answer (score 3):

[Trying Elmah](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx) for trace your logs.